# Integrated Circuit z-impedance

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, transmission-line, microwave

I have an OBU (On-board Unit) circuit and it has a DSRC (Dedicated Short-Range Comm) IC, but I don't have any information about the IC from S11 and Z etc.

I want to ask how can I find the Z-impedance to be able to design a good filter between the IC pin and the output connector?

The Ic is SKY6650
http://www.skyrelay-ic.com/article/5.html

Comment: `I don't have any information about the IC from S11 and Z etc.` do you have datasheets or part numbers? Put links to them.